# Which one is correct to show that "the fan" in not the only one?

Tags: grammar, phrases, vocabulary

Which one is correct?

1. a big fan of yours in millions

or

2. a big fan in millions of yours

Tanx

Comment: Neither is correct. If you provided more context (such as a complete sentence), it would be easier for others to figure out what you are actually trying to say.

Comment: One of your millions of fans. / A big fan of yours (one of the millions).

Comment: Tanx. the second one is nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both of them are awkward, if not wrong. A better, IMHO, phrasing can be:

```
I am one of your millions of great fans.
```

or

```
I am a great fan of yours, amongst millions of others.
```

or

```
I am a bigger fan of yours than the million others you have.
```

Comment: Tanx. Really I mean your second example but I think it's a simple sentence. I need something more creative.
e.g. you can say you can say "I'm one of your big fans" but I think "I'm a big fan of yours" is much more beautiful and sensational.

Comment: More creative to say what? That you are a bigger fan than the millions someone has?

Comment: somehow! to show that you are one of millions while you are different in a way!

Comment: Does the new phrasing cut it?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I included a third phrase. Does it suit your requirement?

Comment: BTW see this link for what I meant. This is a negation of "cut it" but I hope you can infer the meaning from this: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+cut+it

Comment: Sorry, i hadn't seen the edited form. well it's much better but it's very bold like "hey buddy. see me that i"m different!"

Comment: Thank you for your help. So i pick the second one with a little change. Is this correct? "A big fan of yours, among(st) millions"

Comment: Please consider upvoting and/or marking the answer as accepted if you found it useful.